# C++ convert uint8_t to unsigned long

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, casting

I'm transferring some data with spidev using a struct like this

```
struct spi_ioc_transfer tr = {
    .tx_buf = (unsigned long)tx,  // transferred 
    .rx_buf = (unsigned long)rx,  // received
    .len = ARRAY_SIZE(tx),
    .delay_usecs = delay,
    .speed_hz = speed,
    .bits_per_word = bits,
};
```

The data that I want to send is `uint8_t tx[] = {0xAC, 0xDC}`
So I'm casting the array like this: `msg.tx_buf = (unsigned long)tx;`

But this is not good for portability and it's endian dependent. 
Is there a better and fast way to do this?
I also need to compare the values of msg.tx_buf and msg.rx_buf to make sure that the value was written correctly.

Thanks

Comment: What is this syntax with the members of the struct being initialized in that way? That's not valid C++ as far as I know?

Comment: @jcoder: I have seen it before, I think it's related to the C99 spec. and C++0x likely adopted it. Like most things in the newer C and C++ specs it frustrates me because the only thing it really does is make code harder to read :)

Comment: Please use a proper C++ cast instead of C casts.

Comment: code was taken from spidev_test.c. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/spi/spidev_test.c so it's C syntax, no C++. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your "spidev" expects to send 32-bit words (`bits` is 32), then you need to re-arrange the data in memory to be correctly laid out.

You need to do:

```
const uint32_t tx32[] = { tx[0], tx[1] };
```

Then set the `.tx_buf` value to `tx32`, assuming it wants the address of the data to send. Remember to make sure `.len` gets properly set to 2, still.

Answer (score 1):

You can just assemble the both values, using bit and shift operations:

tx_buf = tx[ 0 ] | ( tx[ 1 ] << 8 );

It's portable and it's easy to understand.

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
uint8_t tx[] = {0xAC, 0xDC};
unsigned long* longDataPtr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(tx);
```

Now `longDataPtr` is pointer to result.

However, to use `reinterpret_cast` you need to have `sizeof(unsigned long)` elements in buffer, otherwise result will be corupted.

Comment: I'm not sure this accomplishes what the OP wants. The question mentions byte-order issues, and this only works if the host and end-point have the same byte-order. I'd expect to see something like `htons (...)` and `ntohs (...)` in a portable implementation in situations where the byte-order differs.

Comment: -1, I really don't think this helps. How is the SPI device (which expects a pointer to 32-bit data) going to successfully read `tx` which is still a packed array of single 8-bit values in memory? Also, there's a typo in the C++ cast operator.